# List<Object> abcList and method overloading

Tags: java, hibernate, generics, generic-list

I am wondering if there is a short cut for my current problem.

I have a List abcList.

It contains 3 type of objects/Entity A B C (they did not inherit a common interface or parent, with exception to Object>.

They are hibernate Entity.

I have 3 overloaded method.

```
process(A a)
process(B b)
process(B C)
```

I was hoping to loop the

List abcList and just calling process();

```
for(Object o: abcList) process(o);
```

is there an easy solution for my current problem? I am implementing a class that contain 3 different type of object List.

Answer (score 3):

As the binding is at compile time, it's impossible to know. If you can add an interface to those classes, you can use the Visitor pattern.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the visitor pattern, another thing to consider is putting a layer of indirection in when adding to the list. Instead of putting the object in directly, put in an object that can `process` that has references to both the object and the outer context.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good place for using the [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern). Without resorting to reflection, you'll need to define a common interface for the objects in your List. Let's start there:

```
interface Visitable {
    void accept(Visitor v);
}
```

The Visitor, then, is where you define the process methods for each concrete type:

```
interface Visitor {
    void process(A a);
    void process(B b);
    void process(C c);
}
```

Now, a concrete Visitable is able to invoke the proper overloading of `process()` since it is, of course, aware of it's own concrete type at compile time. For example:

```
class A implements Visitable {
    void accept(Visitor v) {
        v.process(this);
    }
}
```

Classes `B` and `C` will do the same. So now you end up with your processing loop:

```
List<Visitable> abcList = ...;
Visitor visitor = ...;

for (Visitable o : abcList) {
    o.accept(visitor);
}
```

Again, if you are not able to define a common interface for all your classes then you can still achieve this with the [Visitor Pattern using Reflection](http://www.oodesign.com/visitor-pattern.html).